# create list of objects and present them as tiles

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

Right now I have this being produced
[image]

I want them to be next time to each like a 3x3 cube

The below code is generating the stuff in the image.

```
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 10px">
@foreach (var m in Model.FilteredMatches)
{
 <div class="span3">
 <a href=@Url.Action("Details", "Member", new { id = m.UserId }) class="thumbnail">
 <div class="span4 " style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px">
 <img src="@m.Photo.PhotoURL" class="img-responsive " style="max-height:300px;max-width:200px"/>
  </div>
 <div class="span2 " style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px">
 <h5>@m.Username</h5>
<h5>@m.Age year old @m.Gender.WhatGender | Seeking</h5>
<h5>@m.City, @m.State.Name,@m.State.Country.Name</h5>
</div>
 </a>
 </div>
 }
</div>
```

I am also not sure why bootstrap isnt placing the span next to eachother.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of `div`s, which are block elements and will not display next to each other by default. You can give these a width, and then add `float: left;` to your CSS. Your other option is to actually change your `div`s to `span`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var m in Model.FilteredMatches)
{        
<div class="span3 pull-left">
     <a href=@Url.Action("Details", "Member", new { id = m.UserId }) class="thumbnail">
          <div class="span4 " style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px">
              <img src="@m.Photo.PhotoURL" class="img-responsive " style="max-height:300px;max-width:200px"/>
         </div>
          <div class="span2 " style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px">
              <h5>@m.Username</h5>
              <h5>@m.Age year old @m.Gender.WhatGender | Seeking</h5>
              <h5>@m.City, @m.State.Name,@m.State.Country.Name</h5>
         </div>
     </a>
</div>
}
```

Added pull-left to the top div in the above code and it did exactly what I wanted it to do.